# How to show labels of matching fields in a search-api view

Tags: views, search

I have a view that displays search-api results. Is it possible to include a list of the labels of the fields where a match was found?

E.g. when searching for `Ford`:

```
Henry Ford: Title, Body
Fordissimo: Title
Apu Nahasapeemapetilon: Body
```